# pytorch element intersection

Tags: python, pytorch

When I calculate the Hit Ratio, I need to calculate the number of elements of predict tensor in the target tensor, I wanna calculate the number of elements in their intersection.

For example: [# of classes: 20, # of samples: 2]

target:
`tensor([[14, 13,  8, 11, 18, 12,  5,  1,  0, 10],
        [ 8, 10,  2, 10,  7, 17,  6, 12, 13, 14]])`

pred_idx: (HR@5):
`tensor([[14, 11,  8, 19,  4],
        [ 6,  9,  8, 13, 18]])`

now when I do >>> `(pred_idx & target).sum((1,2))`

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (5) must match the size of tensor b (10) at non-singleton dimension 1.
```

But the thing is, the prediction and target have different size, how can I calculate the number of elements in the pred@5 that are also in the target?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could convert to numpy and then use its set operations.

```
import torch
import numpy as np

target = torch.tensor([[14, 13, 8, 11, 18, 12, 5, 1, 0, 10], [ 8, 10, 2, 10, 7, 17, 6, 12, 13, 14]])
pred_idx = torch.tensor([[14, 11, 8, 19, 4], [ 6, 9, 8, 13, 18]])
```

Find elements of p@5 in target:

```
[np.intersect1d(t,p) for t,p in zip(target.cpu().numpy(),pred_idx.cpu().numpy())]
```

Find number of elements in p@5 also in target:

```
[len(np.intersect1d(t,p)) for t,p in zip(target.cpu().numpy(),pred_idx.cpu().numpy())]
```

Comment: plus, I found that 
np.isin(indices[i], grounds[i]).sum()
also works!